# How can I create a custom page for this error?

Tags: errors

How can I create a custom page for this too many connections error page because I know it's because my server is overloaded? I wanted to show a custom error page instead of this when my website is overloaded by traffic.

[image: This is the Error Page.]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out the source of [`dead_db()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/dead_db/) which powers the message.

You'll see that you can create a file `db-error.php` in your WP content directory (which by default is `/wp-content/`) and it'll load that instead!